# Tool that actually prevents Windows 10 telemetry

Tags: security, windows-10, privacy, telemetry

Are there any tools that ***actually*** prevent all Windows 10 telemetry reports from being gathered, or at the least, from being transmitted?

Many tools ***claim*** to do this type of thing, but are there any that actually work completely?

*Note that since Microsoft Windows 10 has no way of blocking specific updates or patches, please, for the purpose of this question, ignore telemetry specifically related to determining what updates/patches will be downloaded and installed by the operating system.*

---

Related, but different question can be read [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/33960/privacy-annoyance-configuration-tool-for-windows-10) (that question requires the recommended software to also deal with other annoyances).